# Angular - How to get an XML file as response instead of a normal HTML page

Tags: angular, xml, sitemap

Here is the scenario I would like to make:

1. User navigates to a predefined route (ex: http://localhost/somefile.xml).
2. Angular dynamically generates an XML based on some data.
3. Angular return an actual XML to the user instead of a normal HTML Page.

The goal is to simulate accessing a static xml resource in Angular.

Can Angular do that?

Edit: For more context, my use case is to dynamically generate a `sitemap.xml` when visiting the url website/sitemap.xml. and return it to the user.

Comment: There is only one html file with SPA. When you navigate in your app, you navigating in that html file. So you probably want to display XML inside HTML?

Comment: @Julius No I don't want to display XML inside HTML, I would like that Angular simulates accessing to a static xml file (ie: When you click `ctrl` + `s` on the browser it must save an xml file not an html one). It's like accessing to a static sitemap.xml in a website

Comment: You can listen for `ctrl` + `s` keyboard events and open save as dialog

Comment: Hello @Julius , my goal is not ctrl + s, the goal is to return an actual XML file to the users instead of a web page like this one https://www.apple.com/sitemap.xml, but this file must be generated dynamically, not add it as a static resource, because I already do that in my application